# Valid range of Landsat L2SP

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, landsat-8

I am using ArcGIS Pro. The given band 4 of a Landsat 8 L2SP product has a range of 75-62460, but in table 6-1 the valid range is 7273-43636. What is this range and also, should I exclude values for my math operations, outside of this range (7273-43636)?

[image]

[image]

[image]